# Rails.application.config.assets.paths, Is this output correct?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to troubleshoot my Rails 3.2 Twitter Bootstrap theme. Some things aren't working correctly. When I run this command I get the following output that doesn't look right or show the paths at all. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

### 1.9.3p125 :003 > y Rails.application.config.assets.paths

- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9mb250
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9pY28=
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9pbWFnZXM=
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9qYXZhc2NyaXB0cw==
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9zdHlsZXNoZWV0cw==
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvdmVuZG9yL2Fzc2V0cy9qYXZhc2NyaXB0cw==
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvdmVuZG9yL2Fzc2V0cy9zdHlsZXNoZWV0cw==
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vLnJ2bS9nZW1zL3J1YnktMS45LjMtcDEyNUBm
  bGV0Y2hlci9nZW1zL2pxdWVyeS1yYWlscy0yLjAuMi92ZW5kb3IvYXNzZXRz
  L2phdmFzY3JpcHRz
- !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vLnJ2bS9nZW1zL3J1YnktMS45LjMtcDEyNUBm
  bGV0Y2hlci9nZW1zL2NvZmZlZS1yYWlscy0zLjIuMi9saWIvYXNzZXRzL2ph
  dmFzY3JpcHRz
- !ruby/object:Pathname
  path: !binary |-
  L1VzZXJzL21hcmtydXNzb24vRG9jdW1lbnRzL3dlYnNpdGVzL2hvc3Rpbmcv
  ZmxldGNoZXIvYXBwL2Fzc2V0cy9mb250
  => nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is absolutely normal. It represents Ruby objects , returned by the command .
You can try this code on your console :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths.each do |p|
  puts p
end
```

What else is not correct in your application?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Now I can read it. All that other digital output didn't make sense to me and I couldn't figure out how to output it correctly.

Comment: Nice to know it's OK . Good luck.